# Note inserting new sub array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So I have this code which save on the first attempt, however when the user visits another station I need it to add a new sub array under the history array.

NOTE: That if nothing is found (meaning `UUID` I still need it to `.save`).

```
const userData = {"UUID": query.uuid, "ipaddress":ip, "history":[{"HID":hid,"station":req.params.stationname, starttime: starttimestamp}]};
                
     var listener = new Listeners(userData);            
     listener.save(function (err, book) {
      if (err) return console.error(err);
      console.log(book.UUID + " saved to collection.");
    });
```

What is the correct way to do this?

I am getting the following error

```
{ MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: AdStitchr.listeners index: UUID dup key: { UUID: "72296e08-2086-3b25-b66f-09fe14e7a1b9" }
    at Connection.<anonymous> (/root/adstichrplayer/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:466:61)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at processMessage (/root/adstichrplayer/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connection.js:384:10)
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (/root/adstichrplayer/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connection.js:553:15)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:250:11)
    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:208:10)
    at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:607:20)
  operationTime: Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 1, high_: 1592964549 },
  ok: 0,
  errmsg: 'E11000 duplicate key error collection: AdStitchr.listeners index: UUID dup key: { UUID: "72296e08-2086-3b25-b66f-09fe14e7a1b9" }',
  code: 11000,
  codeName: 'DuplicateKey',
  keyPattern: { UUID: 1 },
  keyValue: { UUID: '72296e08-2086-3b25-b66f-09fe14e7a1b9' },
  '$clusterTime':
   { clusterTime: Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 1, high_: 1592964549 },
     signature: { hash: [Object], keyId: [Object] } },
  name: 'MongoError',
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }
```

when I use

```
const userData = {"UUID": query.uuid, "ipaddress":ip, "history":[{"HID":hid,"station":req.params.stationname, starttime: starttimestamp}]};
          
  Listeners.findOneAndUpdate(
    userData,
    { userData }, { upsert: true }, function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('ERROR when submitting round');
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have access to the variable `userData` for some reason, and given that it has a valid object value of:

```
const userData = {"UUID": query.uuid, "ipaddress":ip, "history":[{"HID":hid,"station":req.params.stationname, starttime: starttimestamp}]}
```

you can do something like this:

```
Listeners.findOneAndUpdate(
    {"UUID": userData.UUID, "ipaddress":userData.ipaddress },
    { $push: { history: userData.history[0] } }, 
    { upsert: true }, function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('ERROR when submitting round');
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

Comment: This also works, but selected the above answer as that worked and was first.
Thank you though

Answer (score 1):

[`findOneAndUpdate`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/index.html) takes query as a first parameter. What you're doing is you're passing entire object as query including (most likely) non-deterministic `starttimestamp` parameter. MongoDB will try to find such document with only one element in `history` item and when there's no match the `upsert: true` parameter will get applied and MongoDB will try to create a new document (since there's no match). Since you already have another document with such `UUID` you're getting this error.

In order to fix that you need to pass `UUID` and `ipaddress` for the query part and then use [$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) to append you item to the history array:

```
Listeners.findOneAndUpdate(
    {"UUID": query.uuid, "ipaddress":ip },
    { $push: { history: {"HID":hid,"station":req.params.stationname, starttime: starttimestamp} } }, 
    { upsert: true }, function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('ERROR when submitting round');
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```